# Why isn't my iif statement evaluating true when the condition is correct?

Tags: sql, vba, reporting-services, iif

This is my statement:

```
iif(sum(Fields!myfield1.Value) = 0, 0, sum(Fields!myField2.Value)/sum(Fields!myField1.Value))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: where are you putting this IIF statement?

Comment: @Raj More: Likely an SSRS text field, or table cell.  SSRS uses VBA as it's programming language.

Comment: @OMB Ponies: Apologies for the vagueness. I meant to find out if this was used in a SubTotal row or in a Detail row.

Comment: It is in a subtotal row. I've found a VERY unelegant work-around, but a better solution would still be appreciated.

Comment: VBA's IIf evaluates both of its conditions regardless of which one it returns, so it's evaluating both the 0 and the division-by-zero in your example. I don't know SSRS, but that could be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely it *is* evaluating as True. As mentioned in other comments, you'll get an error anyway because Iif() evaluates all parameter expressions regardless of the result of the test.

The error can be avoided by adding another Iif() in the divisor.

```
iif(
    sum(Fields!myfield1.Value) = 0,
    0,
    sum(Fields!myField2.Value) / iif(
                                     sum(Fields!myfield1.Value) = 0,
                                     1,
                                     sum(Fields!myField1.Value)
                                 )
)
```

Now you'll get zero if myfield1 is zero and no error is thrown.

*(You probably should show 'N/A' or just an empty string when the divisor is zero, though.)*