# SSRS Iif always true when false part contains expression

Tags: reporting-services, iif

I've got a report outputting to an Excel file, with some fields in a database being empty.

I'm trying to filter these null values out using the following Iif expression in a cell:

```
=Iif(
    IsNothing(Fields!START_DATETIME.Value),
    0,
    Fields!START_DATETIME.Value
)
```

This doesn't work, I get "`#VALUE`" in the cells where the data was null, and the time value of the cell where there was data.

If I use the same expression without an expression as the third parameter:

```
=Iif(
    IsNothing(Fields!START_DATETIME.Value),
    0,
    1
)
```

I get `1`s where there is a date in the table and `0`s where there is nothing.

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find anything that worked for me...

Edit:
I'm using VisualStudio Professional 2013

**Update**

What I've got for each entry in the database is: a datetime for *authorization time*, another for *start time* and another for *stopped time*. There is always an entry for *authorization time*, but not always for *start* and *stopped*.

I've split the date and time out from the various datetimes into columns like so:

- Authorized date
- Authorized time
- Start time
- Stop time

The idea is that if no start and stop time are present, just use the authorized time

The following expressions are put in the Start time column. Sorry, I don't have enough rep to post images or more than 2 links. I've put program output in this album:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAxM7.jpg

Doing:

```
=Iif(Fields!START_DATETIME.Value is Nothing,
    DateAdd(DateInterval.Day,693594,TimeValue(Fields!AUTH_DATETIME.Value)),
    DateAdd(DateInterval.Day,693594,TimeValue(Fields!AUTH_DATETIME.Value))
)
```

Outputs the *authorized time*, so that works fine.

However, doing:

```
=Iif(Fields!START_DATETIME.Value is Nothing,
    DateAdd(DateInterval.Day,693594,TimeValue(Fields!AUTH_DATETIME.Value)),
    DateAdd(DateInterval.Day,693594,TimeValue(Fields!START_DATETIME.Value))
)
```

Outputs the *start time* where there is an entry, and #VALUE! (null or some such) when there isn't anything.

And doing:

```
=Iif(Fields!START_DATETIME.Value is Nothing,
    DateAdd(DateInterval.Day,693594,TimeValue(Fields!START_DATETIME.Value)),
    DateAdd(DateInterval.Day,693594,TimeValue(Fields!AUTH_DATETIME.Value))
)
```

Outputs the *authorized time* where there is an entry in *start time*, and #VALUE! when there isn't anything.

I can't figure this out. I understand (1) and (3), but what I need is for (2) to display the correct *start time* while there is one, and the *authorized time* when there isn't.

**Update 2**

It turns out that Iif() evaluates each conditions even if it is not selected, and any error encountered is passed on regardless. See comments to [Why isn't my iif statement evaluating true when the condition is correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822233/why-isnt-my-iif-statement-evaluating-true-when-the-condition-is-correct?rq=1)

To fix this I did:

```
=DateAdd(
    DateInterval.Day,
    693594,
    TimeValue(
        Iif(
            Fields!START_DATETIME.Value is Nothing,
            Fields!AUTH_DATETIME.Value,
            Fields!START_DATETIME.Value
        )
    )
)
```

This seems to work for me, and should have been the common sense way to do this in the first place...

Thanks again for your help guys.

Comment: Why do you want "0" in a column with DATETIMEs? What would it represent? Don't you need either NULL, empty string, or some default datetime?

Comment: If you want to filter them out as in "don't show them", can't you do that in your query?

Comment: @Jeroen Anything except #VALUE! would be nice, that was just to try it, I'd probably leave it blank.

Comment: @Tino I can try that, but tbh I haven't touched queries outside of the report designer yet. I'm wondering why the Iif wouldn't work. Thanks for you guys' input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel will *guess* the type of a column based on the first few cells. If there's typical `DATETIME` values in those, it'll guess the column is a date column, and it will error with "`#VALUE!` on values that don't match the type, such as "0".

You should ask yourself what you want to display in Excel for NULL values:

- If you just want an empty cell, don't use an expression at all. Just `Fields!START_DATETIME.Value` will render a NULL value as an empty cell.
- If you want a "baseline" datetime, make sure to use that instead of "0". Easiest is probably in your query with something like `ISNULL(START_DATETIME, GETDATE())`.
- If you *really* want a "0", make sure it appears in one of the first few cells by ordering. Excel will see the "0" and not set the column type to date/time.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I can't believe I didn't think of that. What a chop I was... Sorry I can't upvote, I have too little reputation.

Comment: I can't manage to get it to just have an empty cell. Any idea how Excel stores a blank? `#Value!` is put there when using `Nothing` (null) as the true part of the Iif() expression.

Comment: @user111395 You don't need the `IIF` when `START_DATETIME` is `Null` because its already `Null` so as @Jeroen says just use `=Fields!START_DATETIME.Value` as your cell value expression. +1 @Jeroen for great explanation.

Comment: @ChrisLätta That works, but Excel doesn't know how to format as date or time from this output. I kind of need a time from this so that I can use the filter and sort options in Excel. This is bordering on a new question, but I'm trying to use `DateAdd(DateInterval.Day,693594,TimeValue(Fields!START_DATETIME.Value))`. If it's not possible I'll have to try look into some other options like macros. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: If you want a low constant start date when the `START_DATETIME` is `Null` then set an actual date in your expression (rather than 0) as suggested by @Jeroen in his second bullet point, like so: `=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!START_DATETIME.Value), CDate("1900-01-01"), Fields!START_DATETIME.Value)`